# ¿Cómo inicializo y detengo un for si no se cuantos datos van a ingresar?

Tags: c++, lista, archivo

Necesito un programa que lea un archivo,y en base a los datos del archivo cree una lista simple y calcule algo con esos datos. El programa actual ya lee e imprime la lista, solo me hace falta un for

**PROGRAMA ACTUAL**

```
    struct Datos
    {
          float x,y;
    };
    Datos Ini={0.0,0.0};

    class Nodo
    {
        Datos A;
        Nodo *sig;
     public:
         Nodo(Datos B=Ini,Nodo *s=NULL)
         {
          A=B;//x
          sig=s;//null
          }
          void ModSig(Nodo *t){sig=t;}
          Datos RegDatos(){return (A);}
          Nodo *RegSig(){return (sig);}

          ///Solo valores
          float RegX(){return (A.x);}
          float RegY(){return (A.y);}
    };

class LSE//Esta clase lee, imprime y crea una lista simplemente enlazada
{
     Nodo *st,*ed,*gen;
 public:
     LSE(){st=ed=gen=NULL;}///Comprueba que la lista este vacía
     void Insertar(Datos X);
     void Imprimir();
     void LeerArch();
};

void LSE::Insertar(Datos X)
{
    if(st==NULL)
    {
         gen=new Nodo(X);
         if(gen==NULL)
         {
             cout<<"No hay memoria...\n\n";
             exit (1);
         }
      st=ed=gen;
    }
    else
    {
        Nodo *aux=gen;
        gen=new Nodo(X);
        if(gen==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"No hay memoria...\n\n";
            exit (1);
         }
     aux->ModSig(gen);
     ed=gen;
    }
}

void LSE::Imprimir()
{
     Nodo *i;
     for(i=st;i!=NULL;i=i->RegSig())
     {
         cout<<"\t\t"<<i->RegX()<<"\t"<<i->RegY()<<"\t"<<"\n\n";
     }
}

void LSE::LeerArch()
{
    Datos L;
    ifstream arch;
    char datos[50];
    char nombreArchivo[30];
    cout<<"\n\tDame el nombre del archivo que deseas abrir: "<<"\n  \t\t";
    cin>>nombreArchivo;
    arch.open(nombreArchivo);
    if(!arch.fail())///Si se utiliza != marca error
        {
            cout<<"\n\n";
            while(!arch.eof())
            {
                arch >> L.x;
                arch.get();
                arch >> L.y;
                arch.get();
                Insertar(L);
             }
        arch.close();
        }
        else
            {cout << "\nEl archivo no se pudo abrir" << endl;
            exit(0);}
}

class MinimosCuadrados:protected LSE//Esta clase es la que debe leer el 
                                    //archivo y hacer los cálculos

{
    float a0,a1;//Esto es para hacer unos cálculos
public:
   MinimosCuadrados()
   {
    a0=a1=0.0;
   }
   void MetMC();
};

void MinimosCuadrados::MetMC()
{
    Datos R;
    LeerArch();
    Imprimir();
    for(i=st;i!=NULL;i=i->RegSig())
     // Mi profesor me dijo que implementará este for pero marca error al 
     // introducir el código aquí ya que maneja la parte privada de LSE, 
     //imagino que es algo similar
    {
         //Aquí van los cálculos
    }

}

int main()
{
   system("color F5");
   MinimosCuadrados K;
   K.MetMC();
   system("pause");
   return(0);
}
```

La clase LSE no puedo modificarla, se puede decir que es la base, todo lo tengo que trabajar con la clase MinimosCuadrados... No pido que resuelvan mi tarea  solo requiero de un ejemplo o algo que me oriente...

**PARTE A MODIFICAR**

```
void MinimosCuadrados::MetMC()
{
    Datos R;
    LeerArch();
    Imprimir();
    for(i=st;i!=NULL;i=i->RegSig())/* Mi profesor me dijo que 
        implentara este for pero marca error ya que maneja la 
          parte privada de LSE, imagino que es algo similar*/
    {
         //Aquí van los cálculos
    }

}
```

Este era parte de otro programa que había hecho y realiza lo mismo, funciona bien pero en ese programa modifique la LSE, y mi profe lo rechazo...

**PARTE DE OTRO CÓDIGO QUE HACE LO QUE NECESITO**

```
 void LSE::Cantidades()
 {
             Nodo *i;
             for(i=st;i!=NULL;i=i->RegSig())
             {
             Xi=Xi+i->RegX();
             Yi=Yi+i->RegY();
             XY=XY+(i->RegX())*(i->RegY());
             X2=pow(Xi,2);
             X2i=X2i+pow(i->RegX(),2);
             n=n+1;
             x=Xi/n;
             y=Yi/n;
        }
        cout<<"\n  Numero de puntos: "<<n;
        cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de Xi: "<<Xi<<"\n  Sumatoria de Yi: "<<Yi;
        cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de XiYi: "<<XY;
        cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de X\1362i: "<<X2i;
        cout<<"\n  Xi\1362: "<<X2<<endl;

        a1=((n*XY)-(Xi*Yi))/((n*X2i)-(X2));
        a0=y-a1*x;

        cout<<"\n\n\tLa funcion de la linea recta es:\n\t   Y=";
        cout<<a0<<" + "<<a1<<"x\n\n";
 }
```

Necesito hacer lo mismo en el primer código pero sin alterar la LSE, que quede en la clase de MinimosCuadrados

Comment: Algo falta aquí. `LSE` no tiene ningún método público o protegido para interactuar con esta clase. Tal cual está solo se puede invocar a `Insertar`, `Imprimir` y `LeerArch`. Me temo que hay algun detalle de esa clase que no has incluído en la pregunta porque, como te digo, tal cual está no se puede hacer nada. O eso o hay algún detalle de tu problema que no nos has contado

Comment: En si a LSE solo le falta la función para guardar, se la borre, ya que no la necesito para este programa en especifico porque solo me sirve para introducir datos manualmente y crear un archivo. La función LeerArch() genera una lista simple después de leer y es la que me da los datos... Tal vez no plantee la pregunta adecuada. Para usar esos datos necesito de un for, pero no se como inicializarlo o detenerlo, ya que necesito que se detenga justo cuando termine la lista, pero como viene de un archivo la clase no sabe cuantos datos tiene

Comment: tal y como está la pregunta, `LeerArch` **no retorna nada**, luego difícilmente se podrá usar tal cual está para recuperar la lista que mencionas. Por favor, revisa la pregunta a fondo y editala a conveniencia para que refleje realmente tu punto actual y lo que necesitas... se agradece que elimines código innecesario pero no que borres el que sí hace falta para entender el problema

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder a los datos de la lista tuve que hacer amistad entre la clase LSE y la clase MinimosCuadrados

```
class LSE
{
    Nodo *st,*ed,*gen;
    friend class MinimosCuadrados;
public:
    LSE(){st=ed=gen=NULL;}///Comprueba que la lista este vacía
    void Insertar(Datos X);
    void Imprimir();
    void LeerArch();
};
```

El método quedó de la siguiente manera después de utilizar friend

```
void MinimosCuadrados::MetMC()
{
    Datos L;
    LeerArch();
    Imprimir();
    Nodo *i;
    for(i=st;i!=NULL;i=i->RegSig())
    {
        Xi=Xi+i->RegX();
        Yi=Yi+i->RegY();
        XY=XY+(i->RegX())*(i->RegY());
        X2=pow(Xi,2);
        X2i=X2i+pow(i->RegX(),2);
        n=n+1;
        x=Xi/n;
        y=Yi/n;
    }
    cout<<"\n  Numero de puntos: "<<n;
    cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de Xi: "<<Xi<<"\n  Sumatoria de Yi: "<<Yi;
    cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de XiYi: "<<XY;
    cout<<"\n  Sumatoria de X\1362i: "<<X2i;
    cout<<"\n  Xi\1362: "<<X2<<endl;

    a1=((n*XY)-(Xi*Yi))/((n*X2i)-(X2));
    a0=y-a1*x;

    cout<<"\n\n\tLa funcion de la linea recta es:\n\t   Y=";
    cout<<a0<<" + "<<a1<<"x\n\n";
}
```